# How can I customize the Symfony exception page?

Tags: exception, error-handling, symfony, twig

When there is an exception in symfony 2 it will output the following page:

```
Oops! An Error Occurred

The server returned a "404 Not Found".

Something is broken. Please e-mail us at [email] and let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
```

1. Where is the template for that page?
2. Where can I configure the email to be shown here?

EDIT:
I'm not asking how to overwrite the template as seen here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

I'm asking how to tell symfony the mail address I want it to use (assuming it's possible), I've asked where is the template so I can see myself how to that, and if it's possible.

Answer the question body not the title please!

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

Comment: @KingCrunch question updated... Of course I've seen that!

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception/error.html.twig

Comment: ok, thank you, you can write it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [the official manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) you can [overwrite templates from other bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates)

> All of the error templates live inside TwigBundle. To override the templates, we simply rely on the standard method for overriding templates that live inside a bundle. For more information, see Overriding Bundle Templates.
>   For example, to override the default error template that's shown to the end-user, create a new template located at app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.twig:

You can find the built-in template in the source of the TwigBundle, or can directly [at github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception/error.html.twig). There you can see, that `[email]` is hardcoded.

Comment: Is it possible to put error twig template inside custom bundle instead  of overriding it directly in TwigBundle?